# JavaScript undefined object property returned but not always

Tags: javascript, undefined

I want to access property of object (either by dot notation or associative array style) but most of the time I got 'undefined'.

I cannot find out why because when printing to console, required property is always presented, please have a look at this piece of code.

```
load: function(key) {
    console.log("SettingsUtils - load(" + key + ")");
    //TODO case for querying non-existing setting
    console.log(this.SETTINGS);         // OK
    console.log(this.SETTINGS[key]);    // OK
    var tmp = this.SETTINGS[key];       // OK
    console.log(tmp);
    var result = tmp['current'];        // most of the times undefined, why ?
    //TODO most times is undefined, why ??
    console.log(result);
    if (result === undefined || result === null) {
        result = this.SETTINGS[key].default;
    }
    console.log("return: " + result);
    return result;
},
```

console output fot 7th line:

```
Object
current: true
default: false
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Comment: if the console output you shared comes from `console.log(tmp);`, that's the value of `this.SETTINGS[key]`. It shows the value of the `current` property as `true` so `tmp.current` cannot be `undefined`. To make it more clear you could do a console log both at the begin and end of the function and see when and if in its boundaries ever happened that both `result.corrent` and `tmp.current` didn't have the same value. They won't

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do. What properties are you expecting to see. What is Setting and is there any other code changing Setting?

Answer (score 0):

Thank You all for Your time, I finally found the cause of this strange problem.

It was mishandled promise/async code and poor design in other part of the app that influenced this object state.

Now I got rid of this strange issue.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, but I don't see how anyone else will learn from this experience, since the real cause didn't appear in the question or the answer.  Please consider either elaborating or deleting.